# Android: How do I know how many text can fit in my textView (my page)?

Tags: android, text, textview

I want to create a text reader, which will cut the text and put it in the TextView (represents my pages) and one after the other. These are contained in a ViewFlipper (represents my entire text), which allows me to turn the pages.

By cons I can not cut my text intelligently. For now I limit each TextView to a number of characters, but it is very unstable. Indeed some letters take up more space than others .. We can not use this method.

**How can we know what quantity of text will enter into a TextView?**

I tried to find the maximum size of my View manually .
I invoked in:

```
float test = view.getPaint().measureText(myString);
```

It works well. When I put 480 letters (0 and 1), I get to 14,400 and my text is entirely within the screen. With:

```
1  -> 12.0
0  -> 12.0
é  -> 11.0
\n -> 13.0
\r ->  7.0
```

total to fill the page -> 14400

**The problem is that the line breaks and carriage return are causing problems.**

If I have only letters or numbers in my string, so good: if we respect the maximum size of 14,400, everything is displayed on the screen. No Problem!

By cons, if a line breaks or a carriage return, it does not work. Even if we we respect the limit of 14400, the text above and is not fully displayed.

This is because the "MeasureText" method;" only returns 13 for a line break. But it's weird, a line break should account for at least 480 to make it consistent.

**How do publishers eBook (Moon Reader, + Aldiko) for the text to be formatted so good? Each page has the same height, the text ends in the same place ..**

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the number of lines in your `TextView` by adding `android:maxLines="some_integer"`. The other way is this:

```
if (myTextView.getMeasuredWidth() < myTextView.getPaint().measureText(myText)) {
    myTextView.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
    myTextView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
}
```

But this will add cloudy effect to the last character if the text is too long.

Comment: Thank you but I can not use your code. The "getMeasuredWidth" does not seem appropriate. She returns 0 every time.

Thank you for the "myTextView.getPaint (). MeasureText (myText)" is exactly that I need.

Now I only need a method to determine the maximum capacity of my View. "getMeasuredWidth" does not return anything.

Comment: It does, but the strangest point is that this code always works fine!

Comment: are you trying to do this on the onCreate of an activity?

Comment: is the width of your textView set to wrap_content?

Comment: @118218 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939002/if-i-call-getmeasuredwidth-or-getwidth-for-layout-in-onresume-they-return-0

Answer (score 0):

Before get measured width or height call below method :

```
anyview.measure(0,0);
```

without calling this method you all wage getting `0 value` for `height` and `width`

Comment: And view you are need height and width must be inflated from XML or anemically through code.