# Android ViewPager with dynamic height

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, onmeasure

I have a `ViewPager` to show some Fragments and swipe between them but the height of the `ViewPager` is dynamic based on the content.
Assume I have multiple list that each list placed in one tab and by changing tabs the height of `ViewPager` should change properly
I created a custom `ViewPager` and overrided `onMeasure` but the problem is `ViewPager` creates the next fragment sooner that current fragment (visible one) gets It's height from next fragment measure.

Here is `MyViewPager` :

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public MyViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    
    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int height = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(
                widthMeasureSpec,
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            );
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            if(h > height) height = h;
        }
    
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
    
}
```

I also tried to trigger `onMeasure` method of `MyViewPager` when the fragment become visible like below but nothing changes.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        PostDetailsActivity activity = (PostDetailsActivity) getActivity();
        activity.pagerParent.requestLayout();
        activity.pagerParent.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic height viewpager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330639/dynamic-height-viewpager)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a good solution [here](https://github.com/vabhishek/WrapContentViewPagerDemo) If anyone else was wondering how to make ViewPager change It's height dynamically.

Also you can find quick answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32410274/2381240) If you don't have time to look at Git.