# How do I show sibling views at the end of viewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-framelayout

The `FrameLayout` and `TextView` are not visible even after placing them in `ScrollView`. 
The `ViewPager` and `FrameLayout` are replaced with different `android.support.v4.app.Fragmentgments`.
I want `FrameLayout` and `TextView` to be displayed at the end of `ViewPager`(after scrolling if it exceeds screen height).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_appbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/view_container"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/app_name"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you want a persistent view at the bottom of the `ViewPager`, you can add `android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView` xml attribute inside the `ViewPager`, and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` inside the bottomView.

Comment: Thanks for reply. With above solution, the `viewPager` is scrolling above bottom view. But I want the bottom view to appear at the end of  `viewPager` after scrolling.

Comment: ok, I have your answer, let me add it.

Comment: Finally this link helped me solve my problem -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330639/dynamic-height-viewpager/32410274#32410274

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;  *Simply add `ScrollView` and `FrameLayout` containers inside a layout, inflate this layout inside a `Fragment`, add child fragments to those `FrameLayout` containers in the `onViewCreated()` of this fragment, return this fragment from the `getItem()` of `PagerAdapter`.*

---

Inflate following layout in your MainActivity/MainFragment,

`R.layout.frag_main`:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Setup the `ViewPager` with some `PagerAdapter` and return the required fragment from the `getItem()` method of the adapter like this

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
         return ViewPagerFragment.newInstance(position);
     }
```

inside `ViewPagerFragment`

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = null;
        int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_0, container, false);
                break;
            case 1:
                view = ... //page 1 layout
                break;
            case 2:
                view = ... //page 2 layout
                break;
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (view.findViewById(R.id.view_container2) != null) {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.view_container, new FrameLayoutFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }
```

Now for a page at `position` in the `ViewPagerFragment`, you can inflate

`R.layout.page_0`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <--your ViewPagerFragment content here-->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view_container"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

There you have it

1. Different fragments for `ViewPager` and `FrameLayout`
2. Since `FrameLayoutFragment` is added to the bottom of your `ViewPagerFragment`, it is visible after scrolling down.

Comment: This is not the solution what I want. I have added animation to `ViewPager` and I want only it to be animated. Anyway I solved my problem with above posted link. Thanks for your help.