# Android / Google Maps API - Calculate width and height in pixel of the full Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So im currently making an GoogleMaps based game. Because i wanted to make an camera, i need the size of the whole google map in pixel.

Heres what i mean :

[image: Sizes i actually mean]

I already tried :

```
    // pre generated by android studios
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    int width = mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth();

    int height = mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredHeight();


    String widthAndHeight = width+" "+height;
```

But it only returns null. Whats wrong with the snippet? Any other ways to calculate the full size of the google map ? Or does this just returns the size of the part of the map, which is currently displayed ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939002/if-i-call-getmeasuredwidth-or-getwidth-for-layout-in-onresume-they-return-0

Comment: post answer :D, than im gonna except it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [If I call getMeasuredWidth() or getWidth() for layout in onResume they return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939002/if-i-call-getmeasuredwidth-or-getwidth-for-layout-in-onresume-they-return-0) you can get it working like this:

```
mapView = mapFragment.getView();
mapView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int width = mapView.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = mapView.getMeasuredHeight();

        String widthAndHeight = width + " " + height;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: there is no way to get it from `GoogleMap` object in `onMapReady` callback method?