# in OnAttachedToWindow(...), GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame() returns 0 for all dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm attempting to change the size of my activity in OnAttachedToWindow, so that it appears floating. In order to calculate it's new size, I need to get the visible display frame for the decor view. But it returns 0.

I actually need to get the height of the status bar. I followed this guide: [How to get Android screen height minus status bar in pixel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510824/how-to-get-android-screen-height-minus-status-bar-in-pixel)

But it doesn't work.

How can I get the height of the status bar (or the visible display frame) in OnAttachedToWindow?

I would have thought this possible since, apparently, it has been attached, and drawing can commence, according to the Android docs.

Here is my Activity code:

```
public override void OnAttachedToWindow()
{
    base.OnAttachedToWindow();

    var decorView = Window.DecorView;
    var rect = new Rect();

    decorView.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);

    // rect is now 0

    var lp = (WindowManagerLayoutParams)decorView.LayoutParameters;

    // change some stuff...

    WindowManager.UpdateViewLayout(decorView, lp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs actually state this about `OnAttachedToWindow()`:

> ...it may be called any time before the first onDraw -- including before or after onMeasure(int, int).

That's why I wouldn't really rely on `OnAttachedToWindow()/OnDetachedToWindow()` being in sync with neither `OnMeasure()` or `OnLayout()`.

Is it an idea to override `OnSizeChanged()` method to know when it's measured and apply what you want in there?

Reference: [OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))